# Flag handling until a moderator is chosen?

Tags: support, moderation, comments

Who or how are flags being handled while a mod is chosen? Seems some flags are being handled while others are not.

Comment: Similar questions on Meta Stack Exchange: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/59692/274942, https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/201563/274942. It might take a while - I raised a flag on meta here and it wasn't handled for 17 days! It's not the vault of the Community Managers, though - to be honest, they typically have bigger fish to fry, and that's okay.

Answer (score 7):

Some flags are automatically handled by the community -- for example, enough rude or spam flags deletes a post and enough comment flags deletes a comment.  These actions don't require human intervention.

Otherwise, the SE community managers handle flags on beta sites until moderators are chosen.

Comment: Just wish it was consistent and not bias as I've seen.

Comment: Now it seems like the flag got processed, yet the earlier comment got deleted immediately. Questionable. Thanks for answering Monica